# Is $0^m1^n$ a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

A language is defined as $w = \{ 0^m1^n \mid m, n \in \Bbb N \}$. Is this a regular language? I have seen people proving for both the sides.

[Thread saying it is regular](http://www.urch.com/forums/gre-computer-science/37701-language-0-m1-n-regular.html)

[Proof for it being non-regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480430/show-0m1n-m-neq-n-is-not-regular/2593786#2593786)

Comment: The second link is for the different language where $m$ and $n$ are restricted to be unequal, so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Could you also help me see why adding that restriction stops it from being a regular language, I have intuition, that if you take y = 0, and pump that you might have a case where the number of 0s and 1s will be same in the string.
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $0^*1^*$ trivially a regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

The language $L = \{ 0^{m}1^{n} : m, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is given by the regular expression $0^{*}1^{*}$, which Jack D'Aurizio pointed out.

Now the language $L^{\prime} = \{0^{m}1^{n} : m \neq n \}$ is not regular. To see this, we use the fact that regular languages are closed under the set difference operation. Suppose to the contrary that $L^{\prime}$ is regular. Then:
$$0^*1^* \setminus L^{\prime} = \{ 0^{n}1^{n} :  n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

Is also regular. However, we know that $\{0^{n}1^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not regular, a contradiction. So $L^{\prime}$ is not regular.